# Save several PDFs at once in Google Chrome

Tags: windows, pdf, chrome

I have a Google Chrome window that contains a couple of tabs, some of which being PDFs. I am looking for a program (Windows 7), scripts or extensions that would save all those PDFs at once to a given folder. The best I can think of is AHK or Sikuli.

Comment: who did you do it eventually?

Comment: @user1065869 I haven't had the need since then, I guess one option would be to use the Google Chrome extension [Copy All Urls](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-all-urls/djdmadneanknadilpjiknlnanaolmbfk?hl=en) and feed it to wget. Far from perfect but might gain some time.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you can't. There is no plug-in or feature in Chrome to print multiple tabs.

However this can be achieved in Firefox using [Universal Print](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/universal-print/) extension.

Alternatively use [OneTab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/onetab/chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall?hl=en) plugin for Chrome where you can export all URLs from tabs and generate PDF files externally based on the URLs (there are several tools which can do that).

More advanced solution would include writing [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) script which can use [Chrome Driver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) and automate the process [programatically](https://realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/) by launching [print dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25902227/55075) and save it into PDF. However I didn't test it if that would work.

Alternatively you can try to use [VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096862/print-directly-from-browser-without-print-popup-window) to automate the printing.  Similar to AppleScript on OSX where you can write a script which would [switch between tabs in Chrome](https://superuser.com/q/263198/87805) and [print pages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18212296/55075) into PDF for you.

Comment: That sucks. You are motivated to write all these answers despite the climate and the deletion of some answers. AFAIC I'm done answering in SE Health.

Comment: The Universal Print extension does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use a Google Chrome extension that save the URLs of all opened tabs (e.g. [Copy All Urls](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-all-urls/djdmadneanknadilpjiknlnanaolmbfk?hl=en)) and feed it to downloader like wget, curl, or JDownloader.

Comment: The problem with that is that curl etc. can't do authentication. So if you're trying to save bills, bank statements etc. from your account it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Chrome Extension [Batch Link Downloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/batch-link-downloader/aiahkbnnpafepcgnhhecilboebmmolnn) if all of the PDFs are linked from one page. This extension can download a large number of linked files at once, and you can even choose to download only files whose names match a specific pattern, such as `*.pdf`.